# How do I center this responsive image vertically and horizontally?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, alignment

Okay I have tried to center this responsive image using the vertical-align and text-align property with no luck. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong. I want the image to be vertically and horizontally in the middle of the page.

```
<div class="circle">
     <div class="bl-circle" style="z-index:9999;">
          <a href="http://www.leedsrush.com"><img src="images/Circular.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/leeds.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/Circular.png'" style="width:100%; height:100%;"/>
          </a>
      </div>
</div>

.bl-circle{
    position: absolute;
    max-width:250px;
    max-height:250px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.circle{


}
```

Comment: For `vertical-align` to work, the elements needs to have `display:table`, or `display:table-cell` set. But in this case, if the image is taking up 100% height and width, there's nothing to center.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out this tutorial:

http://pmob.co.uk/pob/hoz-vert-center.htm

This is what I use when I am trying to center an element in my page. Works like a charm every time, especially the example at the bottom when're you don't know the width and height of the element.